# To extend the react-select interface property in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I have customize a react-select drop-down component for my react-project.When i try to extend the interface using React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement | HTMLInputElement>. It shows "No overload matches this call".
I have tried to extend different attributes to get the default values like id, label, name, placeholder, etc.
How can I get the default properties inside the props?
Did anyone experience any similar issue?

**sample code:**

```
import * as React from "react";

import ReactSelect from 'react-select';

export interface SelectProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement | HTMLInputElement> {
    options: Array<any>;
    isMulti: boolean;
    isDisabled: boolean;

};

const Select: React.FC<SelectProps> = (props: SelectProps) => {

    return (<div>
        <label htmlFor={props.id}>{props.label}</label>
        <div>
            <ReactSelect
                {...props}
            />
        </div>
    </div>)
}
export default Select;
```

After using the above code, I am not able to get props.id or props.name, etc.

Comment: I've created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-cohen-l8e42?file=/src/App.tsx Your code seems to be working. The only issue I got, was because of "label" missing in the interface. Are you able to reproduce  your issue in the sandbox?

Comment: Thank you JAM.
Actually, we need to extend react-select instead of normal javascript select. also, we need to get the id, name label by default without adding them inside the interface. like [https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-paper-xgmbe?file=/src/App.js] in this example, I can able to write label without adding inside the interface.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:**

React-Select v5 now natively supports TypeScript, therefore some type changes have been made ([details](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/releases/tag/react-select%405.0.0)).

Here's an updated example for v5 (react-select/async), similar to the original one with v4:

```
import ReactSelectAsync, { AsyncProps } from "react-select/async";
import { GroupBase } from "react-select";

interface CustomSelectAsyncProps {
  additionalCustomProp: number;
}

function SelectAsync<
  OptionType,
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  GroupType extends GroupBase<OptionType> = GroupBase<OptionType>
>({
  additionalCustomProp,
  ...props
}: AsyncProps<OptionType, IsMulti, GroupType> & CustomSelectAsyncProps) {
  return <ReactSelectAsync {...props} />;
}

export default SelectAsync;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-react-select-component-react-select-v5-ts-v4-bjb6wt?file=/src/CustomSelectAsync.tsx)

**Original Answer:**

This is documented on the official [react-select documentation](https://react-select.com/typescript#select-generics).

Quote:

> Wrapping the Select component
> Oftentimes the Select component is wrapped in another component that is used throughout an app and the wrapper should be just as flexible as the original Select component (i.e., allow for different Option types, groups, single-select, or multi-select). In order to provide this flexibility, the wrapping component should re-declare the generics and forward them to the underlying Select. Here is an example of how to do that:

```
function CustomSelect<
  Option,
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>
>(props: Props<Option, IsMulti, Group>) {
  return (
    <Select {...props} theme={(theme) => ({ ...theme, borderRadius: 0 })} />
  );
}
```

It also explains how to extend the props with additional custom props:

> You can use module augmentation to add custom props to the Select prop types:

```
declare module 'react-select/dist/declarations/src/Select' {
  export interface Props<
    Option,
    IsMulti extends boolean,
    Group extends GroupBase<Option>
  > {
    myCustomProp: string;
  }
}
```

But I personally prefer to just add a custom interface using the `&` character with a custom interface to add custom props (example with `ReactSelectAsync`, see `... & CustomSelectAsyncProps`):

```
interface CustomSelectAsyncProps {
  additionalCustomProp: number;
}

function SelectAsync<
  OptionType extends OptionTypeBase,
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  GroupType extends GroupTypeBase<OptionType> = GroupTypeBase<OptionType>
>({
  additionalCustomProp,
  ...props
}: Props<OptionType, IsMulti, GroupType> & CustomSelectAsyncProps) {
  return (
    <ReactSelectAsync {...props} />
  );
}
```

Comment: Trying your solution at the end, but finding TypeScript is complaining about unknown types when I'm using the custom select component. Are you importing the base types from somewhere other than `react-select`?

Comment: Turns out my editor had added `import { Props } from "react-select/dist/declarations/src/Select"` instead `import { Props } from "react-select"`, which is why TypeScript was complaining

Comment: Had to downvote your answer because `OptionTypeBase`, `GroupTypeBase` no longer exist in the current version of `react-select`

Comment: @JasonBert Yup, React-Select v5 was rewritten to TypeScript, so the types have changed slightly.

I will update the answer for v5

Comment: @JasonBert Answer updated :)

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with this approach even after reading some of the answers here.

So here is my full approach:

First of all, ReactSelect does not have a clean interface for their props similar to how you'd extend the Html button, example: `Interface IbuttonProps extends HTMLButtonElement`

The react-select props default props has the interface name `Props` which can be imported from both of these paths:

```
import { Props } from "react-select/dist/declarations/src/Select" instead import { Props } from "react-select"
```

**only the latter `import { Props } from "react-select"`  is correct**!

The `Props` interface also uses generics so it will look similar to this:

```
Props<Option,IsMulti,Group>
```

To extend this interface we'll use [generic type definitions with type parameter defaults](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/generic-parameter-defaults-in-typescript#:%7E:text=Generic%20Type%20Definitions%20with%20Type%20Parameter%20Defaults) like this:

```
type MyCustomSelectProps<Option, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>> = Props<
   Option,
   IsMulti,
   Group
>
```

So when we create our own extension of the react-select Props it will look something like this:

```
type MyCustomSelectProps<Option, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>> = Props<
    Option,
    IsMulti,
    Group
> & {
 MyCustomProperty:string;
 MyOtherCustomProperty:number;
};
```

### Result:

```
import * as Select from 'react-select';
import { GroupBase } from 'react-select';
import { Props } from 'react-select';


type SelectProps<Option, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>> = Props<
    Option,
    IsMulti,
    Group
> & {
    MyCustomProperty:string;
    MyOtherCustomProperty:number;
};


export const Select = <Option, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>>(
    props: SelectProps<Option, IsMulti, Group>,
) => {
    return (<Select {...props}/>)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { omit } from 'lodash';
import Select, { GroupBase, Props } from 'react-select';

type SelectProps<Option, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>> = Props<Option, IsMulti, Group> & {
    label?: string;
    id?: string;
}

const SearchableSelect = <
    Option,
    IsMulti extends boolean = false,
    Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>
>(props: SelectProps<Option, IsMulti, Group>) => {
    const id = props.id || Math.random().toString()
    const reactSelectProps = omit(props, ['label', 'className'])

    return (
        <div>
            {props.label && (
                <label htmlFor={id} className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                    {props.label}
                </label>
            )}
            <Select
                {...reactSelectProps}
                theme={(theme) => ({
                    ...theme,
                    colors: {
                        ...theme.colors,
                        primary: "var(--primary-500)",
                    },
                })}
            />
        </div>
    );
}


export default SearchableSelect
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You can import the `Props` type directly from the `react-select` package.  You probably want to extend it in order to require that `label` and `id` are both defined.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactSelect, { Props } from "react-select";

type SelectProps = Props & {
  id: string;
  label: string;
};

const Select: React.FC<SelectProps> = ({id, label, ...rest}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={id}>{label}</label>
      <div>
        <ReactSelect {...{id, ...rest}} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```