Can't set isMulti on a react-select typescript wrapper with Formik
I am trying to make the most efficient reusable wrapper for React-Select possible using typescript and formik, but I get a typescript error that says "type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'" when trying to include the isMultiProp like this:
const formComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={(values) => {
        console.log(values);
      }}
      initialValues={
        { businessAreaBgForm: [] } as BudgetGroupFormState
      }
    >
      {(formikProps) => (
        <Form className={`${styles['budget-group-form']}`}>
          <div className='form-body'>
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
            <FormSelect<BudgetGroupFormState>
              formikField='businessAreaBgForm'
              formikProps={formikProps}
              label='Business Area'
              isMulti // where I get error
              options={centers.map((center) => ({
                label: center.abbr,
                value: center.businessArea,
              }))}
            />
          );
})};

export interface BudgetGroupFormState {
  businessAreaBgForm: any[]

and here is the FormSelectComponent.
import { FormikProps } from 'formik';
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import Select, { GroupBase, Props } from 'react-select';
import FormElementWrapper from './FormElementWrapper';

interface CustomFormSelectProps<T> {
  label: string;
  tooltip?: ReactElement;
  formikField?: string; // should be globally unique if no id sent bc set as id
  formikProps?: FormikProps<T>; 
}

// https://react-select.com/typescript how to use Props<> type
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/71081394/5570385 how to combine ^ with custom props
type FormSelectProps<
  T,
  Option,
  IsMulti extends boolean,
  Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>,
> = Props<Option, IsMulti, Group> & CustomFormSelectProps<T>;

const FormSelect = <
  T,
  Option = unknown,
  IsMulti extends boolean = false,
  Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>,
>({
  label,
  formikField,
  formikProps,
  tooltip,
  ...overrides
}: FormSelectProps<T, Option, IsMulti, Group>) => {
  const formikConfig = formikField
    ? {
        inputId: formikField,
        name: formikField,
        onChange: (selectedOption) =>
          formikProps.setFieldValue(formikField, selectedOption),
        value: formikProps.values[formikField],
      }
    : {};
  return (
    <FormElementWrapper label={label} tooltip={tooltip}> {/* this is just a label and div wrapper */}
      <Select aria-label={label} isClearable {...formikConfig} {...overrides} />
    </FormElementWrapper>
  );
};

export default FormSelect;

I have no idea how this generic inference works here for isMulti: https://react-select.com/typescript. I don't know what me adding a  to the custom props does, how to test that the Props<Option, IsMulti, Group> for react-select is getting its values still, and why the IsMulti generic variable is always getting set to false. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Does the problem persist when you replace <FormSelect<BudgetGroupFormState> with <FormSelect  and instead use formikProps as BudgetGroupFormState or smth similar?

@josias that fixed it, tysm. I thought that I would have to pass in the T value but typescript was able to inform it, not quite sure how it works still. I am also confused how T is able to be a first parameter inside <> but typescript knows that it can be skipped when inferring Option, IsMulti, and Group.

the issue you are experiencing with your original code is that you are only passing ONE generic type argument.
If you see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678306/typescript-partial-type-inference
And here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10571
TS is based on an all-or-nothing approach. It will not automatically infer the rest of the 4 type arguments for you but take their default values.
